# How do I specify test runner in Serenity tests?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, jbehave

I created a serenity + JBehave + spring boot test.

The test looks as follows:

Story:

```
Meta:

Narrative:
As a new user, in order to efficiently use the service I first want to register to the service and then log in.
During the process I want to make sure that all validations are properly executed

Scenario: user registration
Given a user with email address 'test@test.com' and password 'aaa'
When attempt to register
Then system returns an information about password being too short
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestServer.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest({ "server.port=6666" })
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public class UserRegistrationTest extends SerenityStory {

    private String email;

    private String password;

    @Steps
    private UserRegistrationSteps userRegistrationSteps;

    @Given("a user with email address '$email' and password '$password'")
    public void givenAUserWithEmailAndPassword(@Named("email") String email, @Named("password") String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @When("attempt to register")
    public void attemptToRegister() {
        userRegistrationSteps.openRegistrationPage();

        userRegistrationSteps.enterRegistrationCredentials(email, password);
    }

    @Then("system returns an information about password being too short")
    public void thenSystemReturnsAnInformationAboutPasswordBeingTooShort() {
        userRegistrationSteps.makeSureRegistrationErrorsContainErrorAboutShortPassword();
    }
}
```

When I run the test separately everything goes smoothly. First spring boot server starts, it generates some temporary in-memory database and only then the test is executed. If you run the test separately from the other however, the report is not generated. In order to generate reports I need to execute

> gradle test aggregate

unfortunately, when I do that serenity forgets that I have the @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) annotation at all. It tries to run the test on the server that doesn't yet exist and as a result the test fails.

Here's also my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-gradle-plugin:1.0.59")
    }
}

group 'fi.achivi.server'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'net.serenity-bdd.aggregator'

jar {
    baseName = 'achivi'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure = true

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf', // all spring MVC and spring boot in one dependency
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb',

            'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1', // utils
            'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4',

            'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.0.1.RELEASE', //spring security
            'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.0.1.RELEASE'

    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test',

                'cz.jirutka.spring:embedmongo-spring:1.3.1', //mongodb dependencies
                'de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:1.48.0',

                'net.serenity-bdd:core:1.0.47', // JBehave and serenity stuff
                'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:1.0.47',
                'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-rest-assured:1.0.59',
                'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.0',
                'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.7',
                'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-jbehave:1.0.23'

}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

so how do I make serenity take the @RunWith annotation into account when generating reports, so that my server for the tests is actually generated?

Answer (score 2):

I think you might need to use some kind of SerenityRunner instead of SpringJunit4TestRunner. However this is a little difficult. I've been trying this myself and where I have got to is below.

For some history, you could start with chapter 16 in the Serenity reference documentation.

[Integrating with Spring](http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity-staging/#_integrating_with_spring)

Although out of date, I think it is mostly applicable, and you could use the updated classes, which you'll find in their source code:

`@Rule
    private final SpringIntegrationMethodRule springIntegrationMethodRule = new SpringIntegrationMethodRule();`

and

`@ClassRule
    private static final SpringIntegrationClassRule springIntegrationClassRule = new SpringIntegrationClassRule();`

Some [more up-to-date information](https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/pull/70) is available about these Serenity rules in [the commit](https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/pull/70) for this feature.

In addition to that, if you're on Spring 4.2.0 or later, the Spring team have actually released a couple of Rules themselves, to be used as an alternative to their SpringJUnit4ClassRunner. This is probably the best option if you're on a recent version of Spring.

Here is [an excellent explanation](http://eddumelendez.github.io/blog/2015/08/01/spring-4-2-0-springclassrule-and-springmethodrule/) of how to use the new rules from the Spring team.

**Update:**
I haven't actually managed to get this working myself with the above information - at least with Serenity / Cucumber so I have raised an issue with the Serenity project [here](https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/issues/221). I've also asked this [follow on question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135455/why-is-my-spring-junit-test-rule-not-running) on stackoverflow.